# Why homomorph and not isomorph?

Tags: abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Why are the groups $\mathbb{R},+$ and $\mathbb{R}_0^+,*$ homomorph, their mapping function being $ f: x \rightarrow  e^x $? Why is this not an isomorphism?

Comment: Why not? It is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

These groups are isomorphic, in fact $f$ is an isomorphism with inverse map $x\mapsto \log(x)$, i.e., with $\exp\circ \log=\log\circ \exp=id$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If it were $\mathbb{R}_0$ it wouldn't be, right?